# Slow "Select" Query with varchar(max)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a small table with 500 rows.
This table has 10 columns including one varchar(max) column.

When I perform this query:

```
SELECT TOP 36 *
FROM MyTable
WHERE (Column1 = Value1)
```

It retrieves around 36 rows in 3 minutes.
The varchar(max) columns contains in each row 3000 characters.

If I try to retrieve only one row less:

```
SELECT TOP 35 *
FROM MyTable
WHERE (Column1 = Value1)
```

Then the query retrieves 35 rows in 0 seconds.

In my clients statistics, Bytes received from server, I have:

95 292 for the query retrieving data in 0 sec

over 200 000 000 for the query retrieving data in 3 min

Do you know does it come from?

EDIT --- Here is my real code:

```
select top 36 *
from Snapshots
where ExamId = 212

select top 35 *
from Snapshots
where ExamId = 212
```

EDIT --- More info on clients statistics

The two statistics having a huge variation are:

Bytes received from server : 66 038 Vs  More than 2 000 000

TDS packets received from server 30 Vs 11000

Comment: if the problem already exists, please send the query plan.

Comment: @Toc did you manage to solve this? I'm running in the exact same problem. Only 10 records, 1 column with a nvarchar(max) and some data, but nothing crazy. Takes 3 minutes to do a top 1.

Answer (score 1):

Varchar(max) can't be part of a index key and apart from this other major drawback is it cannot be stored internally as a contiguous memory area as they can possibly grow up to 2Gb. So for improve the performance you need to avoid it.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Index` for `ExamId` also  use `select field1,field2,etc` instead of  `select * ...`.

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try this:

> select * from Snapshots where ExamId = (select top 36 ExamId from Snapshots where ExamId = 212)

Comment: I tried (and replaced "=" by "in") and it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Your execution time should be very low, while fetch is much longer.
Remove the varchar(max) from the SELECT TOP statement and only retrieve those values as you specifically need them.

Answer (score 0):

Include `SET STATISTICS IO ON` before running the `SELECT` query and provide the output. Also, can you post the query plans from the 2 different queries as that will go a long way to explaining what the differences are. You can use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ to upload it and provide the links.

Your `TOP` also does not have a matching `ORDER BY` so you cannot guarantee the ordering of the first 35 or 36 rows returned. This means that the 35 rows may not all be included in the 36 and you *may* be returning hugely different volumes of data.

Finally, also try in SSMS to enable **Client Statistics** with the query - this will show whether the delay is at the server side or all in latency in returning the result set to you.

Answer (score 0):

Without the complete table description as a DDL statement (CREATE TABLE...) and indexes, it is very difficult to answer.

One important question is: do you use the "directive" TEXTIMAGE_ON when creating your table ? This will separate LOBs storage from relational data to avoid row overflow storage...

Answer (score 0):

As other people are saying you should throw `schema (datatype+existing index)` of `Snapshot` table.

In `snapshot` table i believe `examid` is non clustered index which is not unique.
One `examid` has many record.Snapshot table must be having any PK column .

`Top` clause should always be use with `Order b`y clause.`Top` clause without `Order by` clause is `Non Determinstic`.
On what basis it will select `Top N`.
So knowing schema of Snapshot then decide correct Index.

Using `Order by` clause can also be `Non Determinstic` but this is another discussion.

You can try this,

```
create  table #temp(PKID int)

insert into #temp(pkid)
select top 36 pkid
from dbo.Snapshots
where ExamId = 212
```

Then you can do this,

```
select col1,col2,col3,col4
from dbo.Snapshots S
where exists(select 1 from #temp t where t.pkid=s.pkid)
```

Now your main question and problem,

> Why 35 rows retrieve in 0 seconds and 36 rows retrieve in 3 minute.

I will write thst soon here.Meanwhile I am waiting for complete structure of Snapshot table.